# Where can I find the log of IATA code changes for airports with their dates?

Tags: air-travel, airports, online-resources, iata

The IATA code for an airport sometimes change. E.g., IDL was [changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=John_F._Kennedy_International_Airport&oldid=1182704364#Later_operation) to JFK. Where can I find the log of IATA code changes, preferably with the dates of the code changes?

Comment: This **may** be more relevant for https://aviation.stackexchange.com

Comment: Might be behind a paywall https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maintainer of [OpenFlights.org](https://openflights.org) here: as far as I know, **you can't**.

I'm currently working on extending the [existing OpenFlights datasets](https://openflights.org/data) to add the dates when airport started/stopped operating, but even this won't easily let you match airports that change IATA codes straight up.  It's not as simple as comparing coordinates, because there are several cases where one physical airport/field/runway has multiple IATA codes, eg. [Basel/Mulhouse EuroAirport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EuroAirport_Basel_Mulhouse_Freiburg).